# Convert tensorflow saved model from tensorflow object detection api to keras model

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras, object-detection-api, tensorflow-model-garden

Is there a way to export the TensorFlow object detection API saved model to Keras saved model format or can you convert the saved model file to Keras saved model(.h5) format?

Comment: Hi! You can load a saved model and save it to .h5 format using tf.keras.models .  Attached relevant thread for reference . https://backstreetcoder.com/convert-tensorflow-pb-model-to-keras-h5-model/

Comment: This method doesn't work with models created using TensorFlow's object detection API

Comment: Why do you want the model in keras h5 format ? Any issue you are facing with savedmodel format ?

Answer (score 0):

Import the modules:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
```

Load the saved model from TensorFlow:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('path/to/tf_model')
```

Save the model in Keras format (`.h5`):

```
model.save('path/to/keras_model.h5')
```

This should work.